# Data layer allowing query building

Tags: sql, data-access-layer, query-builder, weak-typing

I need to deliver a small app allowing the client to create queries (or "rules") against their local database and trigger certain actions (send mails, text messages and stuff).

Since they will be allowed to state the actual SQL for the job, I am wondering how my data layer is supposed to look like. It seems I don't have any need for entities and repositories, because all data interaction will be weakly typed.

So what should my data layer do? Open the connection, accept the input SQL, and return a list of property bags? Do I even need a data layer for this?

**[Update]**

This is what client wants to have in his app, to be able to write or build queries against their database. It will run on their local computer, meaning that SQL injection attacks are unnecessary for a malicious employee.

But even if I have a visual control for building the query, validating and sanitizing it, the end result of this layer is SQL code, isn't it? How do I abstract that if I want to test it?

Comment: Are you saying they need a reporting database to analyse their business, or that they need to be able to crate conditional alert rules based on the application database, such as "if quantity < re-order level, text these numbers with a re-order message?

Comment: @Steve: conditional alerts only, and rather simple ones actually. This is actually a requirement that came in rather late (I thought that they only need a couple of fixed rules), so there is not much room to change price and deadlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we had the almost same problem more than 10 years ago (though it was not on a local database). IMHO for ad-hoc SQL queries (however they are created, the user could just have a textual shell to type them in), a DAL does not make much sense - for the generic reporting / query part of the application. That does not mean you cannot have a DAL for the parts of the application where data is modified or entered into your database.

You should, however, take care for some things. Obviously, syntactically incorrect queries should give a meaningful error message, and there should be a possibility to interrupt long-running queries.

It may be also a good idea to restrict the ad-hoc query access to certain tables, or provide a layer of certain views, to hide technical parts of your data model away from your users. And I would avoid to allow your users to modify any data in a similar ad-hoc manner - make sure they cannot inject any UPDATE statements into a SELECT statement created by them.

Comment: Thanks, this is good to know. Well, it's a really tiny app actually: for example, it should check their clients' appointment dates and send them a reminder when due, and several other rules like that. But they want the freedom to modify them and create completely new rules, and they have a really large number of related tables making it difficult to predict what they will really need. Yes, I will prevent anything but `SELECT`, but the part about not having a DAL is news to me, even for a small app like this.

Comment: And there is even not much sense in abstracting the DBMS when their queries will be specific to their existing technology anyway.

Comment: @Dilbert: the intended audience makes also a difference: when you assume your users have SQL knowledge to some degree, you can keep a lot of things much simpler as if they had not. For example, two months ago we created a simple Excel-based solution where our users have a sheet with ~100 select statements they can extend on their own, those are preprocessed, executed one-by-one against a DB and the results are assembled / merged into a result sheet for further evaluation. Works like a charm, but only for a specific (inhouse) user base.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it is considered dangerous to accept `SQL` or any inputs to the `SQL` query directly from the user, as such a code would be prone to [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Instead, if this is not a one-off case, and a case where you want to give your users the flexibility to query anything, you should define an intermediate language that the users would use to specify their filtering criteria, which will be used for SQL query generation. This way, you have

1. a chance to sanitize the user inputs before adding them to your query.
2. decoupled your object model from the users, so that if you want to change the object model or the storage itself later on, the users will not be affected at all as long as you write the adapter from this intermediate language to the modified object model or new storage.

We did this in one of our projects to provide users the flexibility to filter, sort, group on any attributes of the underlying data model and this approach works really well.

Comment: Well, this is an application running on their local machine, which means the user can simply set the entire PC on fire. I nevertheless thought about sanitizing it to prevent accidental db updates, but forcing them to learn an intermediate language which will have to support various SQL features seems an overkill for both parties. And it's only a single small project for a single customer so I think there is no sense in doing that.

Comment: But ultimately, even with the mentioned intermediate language, if it compiles to SQL, it turns out that I won't need the strongly typed data layer.

Answer (score 1):

Build a reporting database / star schema using PL/SQL or better an ETL tool which will allow you to clean / enrich the data, pre-apply business rules, use business language for columns and tables rather than technical terms and make the user queries return fast, and put a reporting tool like Cognos over the star schema which pre-joins all the tables for the user and allows you to apply governorship rules to prevent silliness from the users.

That is the simplest, most effective way, but is not cheap.

Comment: Thanks! Although, most effective? Probably. But simplest? In my case, I doubt. :)